# How to get data feed of a stock, with trend data in it ?( like a RSS feed)

Tags: java, python, rss, stock

I am developing an application and would like to get data feed from any source that has the stock symbol of stock exchanges like NYSE, AMEX or Nasdaq, and the "trend" +, -, or = with it ? I want to be able to subscribe to this service provider and receive either delayed or real-time data ? ( like a RSS feed ) The ones I have looked at - have the stock price, but not the "trend". Any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: The trend can be calculated by comparing the last received stock price with latest received stock price.

Comment: Thanks henrik .. Good idea.